# Work around CORS Ember error for a Rails backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, cors

Building a front end interface using a Rails REST API, I get the error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.example.com/questions
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I've set up my adapter to be

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api/v1',
  host: 'http://www.example.com'
});
```

If I was building the API, I would just include the gem 'rack-cors' and allow for the access to other sites, but this is not included in the source. I'm just starting out with the Ember framework and haven't yet found a work around for this.

I've tried running a proxy server

```
ember s --proxy http://www.example.com
```

But I get the same response. Is there a piece of middleware or a method on the RESTAdapter that I can use to bypass this error?

Comment: If you are saying you can't control the server, I think the only alternative is to implement a proxy server yourself.

Comment: @Coder_Nick did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#using-ember-cli), you are creating a proxy server on your server correctly. By doing this, your remote calls will go to the 'http://www.example.com' via your proxy server.

But, you are not using this proxy server. You are sending your remote calls **directly** to the 'http://www.example.com'. Because of the `host` parameter of your adapter:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api/v1',
  host: 'http://www.example.com'
});
```

Change your `host` parameter and send your remote calls to your proxy server. (Your proxy server is located at http://localhost:4200)